# Why are modifiers allowed for a package when they don't seem to do anything?

Tags: java, eclipse

I can declare the following package with modifiers but it doesn't seem to have any effect on anything:

```
private public protected static final package com.stackoverflow.mangodrunk

// ...
class Whatever {
    // ...
}
```

So my question is, does adding a modifier before a package decleration do anything and why would it be allowed by the compiler?

**Update**: Seems to be an issue with the compiler bundled with Eclipse, as others have mentioned this is a compiler error using Sun's JDK.

Comment: Holy crap, you're right, the Eclipse compiler compiles this just fine....

Comment: This is a fairly minor bug, but if you want to report it, you can do it here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're not. Which compiler are you using?

```
$ javac com/stackoverflow/mangodrunk/Whatever.java

com/stackoverflow/mangodrunk/Whatever.java:1: class, interface, or enum expected
private public protected static final package com.stackoverflow.mangodrunk;
                                      ^
1 error
```

Comment: I'm using JDK 1.6.0_17, and you're correct, it has a compiler error when I try to compile it using javac. But under eclipse there is no problem.

Comment: What does that say about the Eclipse JDK?

Comment: Probably a minor error in their grammar causing it to ignore *anything* before "package" not just comments? See if other keywords are ignored too. I guess you should report the bug unless it has been reported already.

Comment: It should ignore annotations *and* comments before the `package` keyword, but it ignores everything. And it's still a problem with Eclipse 3.8/4.2.

Answer (score 4):

According to the JLS, the only thing that can precede `package` is an annotation.

> ```
> PackageDeclaration:
>         Annotationsopt package PackageName ;
> ```

But an annotation looks like this (full grammar omitted for brevity):

> ```
> NormalAnnotation:
>         @ TypeName ( ElementValuePairsopt )
> ```

So your compiler should not be allowing standard access modifiers.

Source:  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html